# How to roll surplus to the next empty date

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a data structure as in example below. We can utilize only one item per date, so the surplus is calculated as `total_items - 1`. This surplus does not have an expiration date.

The surplus should be distributed across subsequent dates where `total_items = 0`, and again only one item per date can be used.

I tried to keep `rolling_surplus` per date, but I don't know how to implement `rolling_surplus_spent` without using a recursive pattern.

So this table

```
date       | total_items |  surplus
------------------------------------
2021-01-01 |         0   |       0
2021-01-02 |         2   |       1
2021-01-03 |         2   |       1
2021-01-04 |         0   |       0
2021-01-05 |         1   |       0
2021-01-06 |         0   |       0
2021-01-07 |         0   |       0
2021-01-08 |         3   |       2
2021-01-09 |         0   |       0
2021-01-10 |         0   |       0
```

should be transformed into this one

```
date       | total_items |  surplus | filled_in
------------------------------------------------
2021-01-01 |         0   |       0  |      0
2021-01-02 |         2   |       1  |      0
2021-01-03 |         2   |       1  |      0
2021-01-04 |         0   |       0  |      1
2021-01-05 |         1   |       0  |      0
2021-01-06 |         0   |       0  |      1
2021-01-07 |         0   |       0  |      0
2021-01-08 |         3   |       2  |      0
2021-01-09 |         0   |       0  |      1
2021-01-10 |         0   |       0  |      1
```

Comment: It looks like `filled_in` will either be `1` (if the other two numbers are zero) or `1` if the other two numbers are _not_ zero. However, what should happen if there was not a previous surplus to be able to 'fill in' a later day? Can you update your example to show what should happen then?

Comment: That would be rows 2021-01-01 (no previous surplus) and 2021-01-07 (surplus runout). I removed zeros from filled_in for better readability.

Comment: It might be more readable, but if you want zeros in the output then you should show that in your sample data too. Presumably the fields are integers, so they shouldn't be blanks.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, placed zeros back.

Comment: You could use a Window Function. I'm not skilled at it, but it would involve taking the sum of `total_items - surplus` for all previous lines, plus a `CASE` statement to determine whether to fill_in based on the values in the current line.